# About sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score documentation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scoring

There is a example in  sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score documentation.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score
y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
y_scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
average_precision_score(y_true, y_scores)  
0.83
```

But when I plot precision_recall_curve

```
precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_scores)
plt.plot( recall,precision)
```

I got the picture:[image]

why the area under the precision_recall_curve is not 0.83?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation, the value is not exactly the area under curve, it is
$$\text{AP} = \sum_n(R_n - R_{n-1})P_n.$$
which is a rectangular *approximation*.

For your specific example, i.e.

```
      R     P
  1   0.0   1.0   
  2   0.5   1.0   
  3   0.5   0.5   
  4   0.1   0.66
```

it is calculated as
$$\begin{align*}
\text{AP} & = \overbrace{(0.5 - 0.0)\times1.0}^{(R_2 - R_1)P_2} + \overbrace{(0.5 - 0.5)\times 0.5}^{(R_3 - R_2)P_3} + \overbrace{(1.0 - 0.5) \times0.66}^{(R_4 - R_3)P_4} \\
&= 0.5 + 0.00+ 0.33 = 0.83
\end{align*}$$
which is the area under the red curve as illustrated below:

[image]

compared to $$\text{AUPR}=0.5 + \overbrace{\frac{0.5 + 0.66}{2}  \times 0.5}^{\text{trapezoid area}} = 0.79$$
which is the area under the blue curve.

Comment: Beat me to it; in particular, the documentation states "This implementation is not interpolated and is different from computing the area under the precision-recall curve with the trapezoidal rule, which uses linear interpolation and can be too optimistic."